# Call notifyDataSetChanged() within Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager in `MainActivity.java` with five Fragments.

Now I've got a problem.

Running `notifyDataSetChanged()` works fine like this:

```
viewpager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But how can I run `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a Fragment?

I have no idea.

**What I've tried**

Making ViewPager static and then run

```
 MainActivity.this.viewpager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to your `MainActivity` like

```
public void dataChanged() {
  viewpager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and from your fragments call it with

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).dataChanged();
```

Comment: I've got another question: On some devices notifyDataSetChanged just refreshes the fragment, which is active. Why it does this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by various methods:

1. The easiest one - declare a public method in MainActivity.java as following:

   `public void onDataSetChanged(){
       if(viewPager != null) {
          viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
       }
   }`

And then call it from the fragment like this:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()). onDataSetChanged();
```

2. Using Interface: You can create your own interface as :

`public interface OnDataSetChangeListener {
        void onDataSetChanged();
}`

Declare and define an instance of it in MainActivity.java and then set it to the instance of your fragment. Then call it from fragment as:

```
onDataSetChangeListener.onDataSetChanged();
```

3. Using EventBuses.

And many more.